# Can't solve a quartic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

I'm trying to solve an algebraic question.The question wants me to solve $n^4+2n^3+6n^2+12n+25=m^2$.The question also states that n is a positive integer and the answer for $n^4+2n^3+6n^2+12n+25$ is a square number. Here's how I tried to solve it:

$$n^4+2n^3+6n^2+12n+25=\\n^4+6n^2+2n^3+12n+25=\\
n^2(n^2+6)+2n(n^2+6)+5^2=\\
(n\sqrt {n^2+6})^2+2n(n^2+6)+5^2.\\$$

Because $a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2$,so

$\sqrt {(n\sqrt {n^2+6})^2}\cdot\sqrt5^2=n(n^2+6)$

Then:

$$n\sqrt {n^2+6}\cdot 5=n(n^2+6)\\
\sqrt {n^2+6}\cdot 5=n^2+6\\
25(n^2+6)=n^4+12n^2+36\\
n^4+12n^2+36=25n^2+150\\
n^4-13n^2-114=0\\
(n^2+6)(n^2-19)=0\\
n^2=19\\
n=\sqrt 19$$

But $n$ is a positive integer.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean $n^4+2n^3+6\color{red}{n}^2+12n+25$? And do you mean to have ${}=0$ at the end?

Comment: I mean $n^4+2n^3+6n^2+12n+25$ is a square number...

Comment: Please edit that into the question.  You can write it as $n^4+\ldots =m^2$ and specify that $n,m$ are positive integers.  Usually when people talk of solving a polynomial (though there is nothing to solve) they mean set it to zero and solve the equation or factor the polynomial, which amount to the same thing.  Do you mean $6^2$ in the middle or $6n^2$?

Comment: Try a few values of $n$ and you'll probably find one...

Comment: Although $n=0$ fails as a solution because it is not positive, there is another single-digit value for $n$ that works.

Comment: Ya but Im trying to solve it...I can't just guess it out...

Comment: Actually, this $n>1$ is the only Fibonacci number which is a perfect cube. So stop guessing, think (or compute!).

Comment: @DietrichBurde, how is that related to Fibonacci?

Comment: $n=0$ and $n=8$ are the only solutions less than $3000$.

Comment: @lhf $n=8$ is the only Fibonacci number which is a perfect cube, except for $n=1$ of course.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But why do Fibonacci numbers enter into the question at all?

Comment: ummm. There are easy bounds, the thing can be square, for nonnegative $n,$ only when $n \leq 8.$ Answer posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ ( n^2 + n + 2 )^2 = n^4 + 2n^3 + 5n^2 + 4n + 4 $$

$$ ( n^2 + n + 3 )^2 = n^4 + 2n^3 + 7n^2 + 6n + 9$$ 
The second one is larger than yours, meaning yours **cannot** be square, when
$$ 7n^2 + 6n+9 - 6n^2 - 12 n - 25 > 0 \; , \;  $$
$$ n^2 - 6n - 16 > 0 \; , \;  $$
$$ (n-8)(n+2) > 0 \; .    $$
You need check only $0 \leq n \leq 8.$

**ADDED**: the quartic in the question also lies strictly between consecutive squares when $n \leq -3.$ The squares are just $n=-2,0,8.$

Answer (score 0):

I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that $a^2-b^2$ only has factors $1, a^2-b^2, (a-b), (a+b)$ if $a$ and $b$ are coprime. Using this, we have that:

$$n^4+2n^3+6n^2+12n+25=m^2 \to n(n^3+2n^2+6n+12)=m^2-25$$

If we assume that $m\neq 5k,k\in\Bbb Z$, by what I stated earlier we have that either $n=1$ and $(n^3+...)=m^2-25$, which leads to $m=\pm\sqrt{46}$, or $(n^3+...)=1$ and $n=m^2-25$, which leads to $n\approx -1.896\to m\approx\sqrt{23.104}$, or that $(n^3+...)=n\pm 10\because m^2-25=(m+5)(m-5)$ and these factors are $10$ apart. Neither of these yields integer solutions, so we can safely discard them too.

In short, this is *impossible* unless $m$ is a multiple of $5$. Now see if you can find if it works when $m$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Above equation shown below:

$n^4+2n^3+6n^2+12n+25=m^2$

As pointed out by Will Jagy the only positive 
integer solution to above equation is 
$(n,m)=(8,75)$

Also $m$ is a multiple of five as mentioned by Rhyes hughes